# Complexity of finding solutions for a system of polynomial equations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, computational-complexity

**Problem A**: Given a set of polynomial equations $ f_1=0,\ldots,f_m=0 $, where the $ f_i $'s are multivariate polynomials with $ n $ variables over a field $\mathbb F$, decide whether there is a (simultaneous) solution to these equations.

**Question**: What is the computational complexity of Problem A?

Note: Over finite fields $\mathbb F$, Problem A seems to be NP-complete. But what about over the reals, rationals, complex numbers?

Comment: What does "computational complexity" mean over the real or complex numbers? Over the rational numbers, it's open whether this problem is even decidable (as far as I know, anyway). It's known to be decidable over the reals by a result of Tarski (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Model_Theory:_decidability_and_quantifier_elimination) and I think known even earlier over the complex numbers (a modern approach is through Grobner bases: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis), but you should specify what "complexity" means in this context.

Comment: For a survey of what was known as of 2003, see Poonen's _Hilbert's tenth problem over rings of number-theoretic interest_ (http://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/aws2003.pdf).

Comment: In fact, strictly speaking (as far as I know, again) it's strongly suspected, but not proven, that this problem is decidable over $\mathbb{Q}$ even for the very special case that the $f_i$ define a curve of genus $1$. Essentially the only cases over $\mathbb{Q}$ that are known to be decidable are when the $f_i$ define a finite set of points together with a finite union of curves of genus $0$. See Poonen, again, _Rational points on curves_ (http://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/millennial.pdf).

Comment: Over the rationals, it's not known to be decidable. Over the complex numbers, it's classically known to be decidable by elimination theory (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elimination_theory) although, as I said, I think a more modern approach would go through Grobner bases. I'm not sure what you mean by your comment about the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: You can assume that the coefficients are rationals to avoid dealing with real number inputs (which I think is the usual way to define the problem).

Comment: @Dilworth, the important thing is the field that contains the solutions not the field that coefficients are coming from. That is the classical setting where the problem is studied.

Comment: @Dilworth, I didn't say you can assume that. What I am saying is the classical problem is when the coefficients are from the countable Q. The problem can be studied when the coefficients are from an uncountable field like R but then the problem is not classical computability problem and is not comparable to the classical Diophantine problem. It is also not (classical) complexity theory, P and NP are for classical problems where inputs are finite objects.

Comment: @Dilworth, If that is what you want (i.e. coefficients from an uncountable field) then you have to specify what model of computation you are going to use, the answer will depend on that. See [this](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2119/the-reasons-for-bss-real-ram-model-being-prefered-in-computational-geometry) to get an idea of why you need to specify the model for computation over reals.